# AJAX AsyncPostBackTrigger for MVC and .Net Application Not Updating

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am having trouble getting data to update Asynchronously in my MVC application, but I have no problem with the same code in the .net application. It is a simple gridview linked to a database and I want to update the data in the gridview every few seconds without a reload of the entire page. It works perfectly in the .net application, but I get the following error in MVC:

"JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."

The actual page is static and will not update. The error goes away if I use a standard Postback trigger, but I do not want to use a postback trigger as it just causes the entire page to reload.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Livebids</title>
    <script runat="server">
    protected void OnTimerIntervalElapse(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { CurrentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); }



</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="CurrentTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>       
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="ctlTimer"
                    Interval="1000" OnTick="OnTimerIntervalElapse" />   
    <div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Item_URL" DataTextField="Item" 
                            Target="_blank" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Bid" HeaderText="Bid" SortExpression="Bid" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="BPM" HeaderText="BPM" SortExpression="BPM" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:qbrdataConnectionString2w %>" 
                    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:qbrdataConnectionString2w.ProviderName %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT livebids.ID, livebids.ProductName, Max(livebids.BidPrice) AS 'Bid', count(livebids.Tstamp) AS 'BPM', scrape1_scraped.Item_URL, scrape1_scraped.item  FROM livebids , scrape1_scraped WHERE livebids.ID =  scrape1_scraped.ID AND livebids.Tstamp &gt;= now() - interval 1 minute AND livebids.BidPrice &gt; 0 group by livebids.ID ORDER BY scrape1_scraped.End_Time ASC limit 40;">
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ctlTimer" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This works well in asp.net, but MVC I get errors and no data update without postback.